# Extract version from filename in bash with grep

Tags: bash, grep

I'm writing bash script which iterate through files in my directory .
I need to extract version from one filename .

As far as

```
grep -Po '(?<=develop.)[^_]+'
```

works great in terminal, in bash script it is not working .

```
echo $filename | grep -Po '(?<=develop.)[^_]+' # great
version  =  $filename | grep -Po '(?<=develop.)[^_]+' # version: command not found
```

file pattern

```
software_1.2.1~develop.3421-1_.deb
```

I expect 3421-1 in output

Any tip ?

Comment: Not working means?

Comment: What is the format of your files' names ? What format do you expect in output?

Comment: Expected behaviour expected with the question :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifications needed:

- No whitespace(s) around `=` while declaring variables in `bash`
- Some process that writes the variable's content on STDOUT so you can use pipe to make it available on `grep`'s STDIN e.g. `echo` here (or here string `<<<`)
- To save the output of a command in a variable, use command substitution `$()`

So, do:

```
version=$(echo $filename | grep -Po '(?<=develop.)[^_]+')
```

Although in this case you would get away without using double quotes, on almost all other cases use double quotes around your variable expansion to prevent from word splitting and filename expansion.